# Changing CSS Properties Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

For some reason this doesn't make the "errorJS" div visible. Can someone please help me?

```
function checkLogin()
    {
        document.getElementById("errors").style.display = "none";
        var form = document.getElementById("form1");
        var problems = false;
        document.getElementById("errorJS").innerHTML = "";
        if(form.email.value.length < 1)
        {
            document.getElementById("errorJS").innerHTML += "Please enter your email address. <br />";
            problems = true;
            document.getElementById("errorJS").style.display = "box";
        }
        if(form.pword.value.length < 1)
        {
            document.getElementById("errorJS").innerHTML += "Please enter your password.";
            problems = true;
            alert(document.getElementById("errorJS").style.display);
            document.getElementById("errorJS").style.display = "box";
        }
        return !(problems);
    }
```

Stupid me, I can't believe I made that mistake. I've been coding more too many straight hours. Thanks to all for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value "box" is not accepted.  It should be "block".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
document.getElementById("errorJS").style.display = "box";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("errorJS").style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try changing style.display = "box" to "block" for both instances?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp